# How can i configure my aws credentials in shared credentials file for github action

Tags: amazon-web-services, gulp, github-actions, cicd, amazon-ecr

I am trying to deploy the ci/cd pipeline for ECR in AWS.

It will push/pull the image from ECR

We are trying to migrate the azure pipeline to GitHub actions pipeline

When I try to implement the pipeline I am facing the below error,

```
[05:25:00] CredentialsProviderError: Profile Pinz could not be found or parsed in shared credentials file.
    at resolveProfileData (/home/runner/work/test-api/test-api/node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-ini/dist-cjs/resolveProfileData.js:26:11)
    at /home/runner/work/test-api/test-api/node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-ini/dist-cjs/fromIni.js:8:56
    at async loadFromProfile (/home/runner/work/test-api/test-api/node_modules/@pinzgolf/pinz-build/dist/publish/aws/GetCredentialsFromProfile.js:23:25)
    at async BuildDeployContext (/home/runner/work/test-api/test-api/node_modules/@pinzgolf/pinz-build/dist/publish/DeployContext.js:95:70)
    at async Publish (/home/runner/work/test-api/test-api/node_modules/@pinzgolf/pinz-build/dist/publish/Publish.js:14:21)
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Here is my workflow YAML file,

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

name: Node Project `my-app` CI on ECRjobs
jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node 14.17.X
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: 14.17.X     
    
    - name: 'Yarn'
      uses: borales/actions-yarn@v2.3.0
      with:
        cmd: install --frozen-lockfile --non-interactive
    
    - name: Update SAM version
      uses: aws-actions/setup-sam@v1
    - run: |
        wget https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/releases/latest/download/aws-sam-cli-linux-x86_64.zip
        unzip aws-sam-cli-linux-x86_64.zip -d sam-installation
        sudo ./sam-installation/install --update
        sam --version

    - name: Configure AWS credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: us-east-2

    - name: Login to Amazon ECR
      id: login-ecr
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

    - name: Build, tag, and push the image to Amazon ECR
      env:
        ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        ECR_REPOSITORY: test-pinz-api
        IMAGE_TAG: latest
      run: |
        gulp publish --profile-name development
```

Using gulp we publish the environment using below config file,

```
{
    "apiDomainName": "domain",
    "assetsDomainName": "domain",
    "awsProfile": "Pinz",
    "bastionBucket": "bucketname",
    "corsDomains": ["domain"],
    "dbBackupSources": ["db source", "db source"],
    "dbClusterIdentifier": "cluster identfier",
    "designDomainName": "domain",
    "lambdaEcr": "ecr",
    "snsApplication": "sns",
    "snsServerKeySecretName": "name",
    "stackName": "name",
    "templateBucket": "bucketname",
    "userJwtPublicKey": "token",
    "websiteUrl": "domain",
    "wwwDomainName": "domain",
    "wwwEcr": "ecr repo"
}
```

I couldn't find the shared credential file where the AWS credentials are saved.

I don't have any idea where the below profile configured

```
"awsProfile": "Pinz"
```

I analyzed all project files but couldn't get the shared credentials

I analyzed this in many documents and ended up with some nearer answers but couldn't get the exact answer. below it says ~/.aws/credentials. but how does above JSON file get the credentials from there?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-shared.html

Honestly, this ECR pipeline deployment is my first time. Also, I didn't get proper KT about the process as well.
I think am almost done on this but for gulp it shows this error

Can anyone please guide me to where will be this shared credentials file? If not how can I configure the AWS credentials to authenticate with AWS?

Answer (score 1):

**Your gulp file has the profile set to `Pinz`, remove this line completely.**

```json
{
    ...
    "awsProfile": "Pinz",
    ...
}
```

The action will [automatically pick up](https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials/blob/master/index.js#L304) on your access key ID & secret access key, proceeding to then [exporting](https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials/blob/f350a92ff69fd554f899e98aab20b45b73283ee4/index.js#L142) them as environment variables that the AWS SDK can use.

The rest of the pipeline should pick up on the configured credentials automatically.

Comment: yeah, this is what I did after posting this question. As you said it picks up the default credentials.  but again I am facing gulp publish error like ''Error: Invalid publish profile named development" which is from the last command $ gulp publish --profile-name development. I am just stucked at the last command.

Comment: I need a permanent fix for this brother. It is a temporary fix for my testing environment. but for real deployment I shouldn't do this. I should deploy with a profile name as it is. Still, I am working on it and facing issues.